# Flex 3 + Flash 11

Tags: flash, apache-flex, debugging

I've used Flex 3 a few years back to build a swf application.

I now need to make some change to it, but in the meantime Flash went from 9.x to 11.x and now Flex cannot run in debug mode because it doesn't handle flash 11 debugger.

I don't intend to upgrade Flex, so what can I do?

I tried downloading 9.x but it won't let me install due to the more recent version currently installed on my system.

Comment: If you don't intend to upgrade; you're a bit stuck.  You can probably overlay the current FlashPlayerGlobals / AIR SDK on top of a Flex 3 framework.  I'd consider that an upgrade, though.  You could also uninstall Flash completely, and then install the 9.x version.  I had no idea that Flash Debuggers were not backward compatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I remember, you can compile with a different player.swc with Flex. If it is not managed on basic settings, you can download the swc on adobe website and try compiling by adding manually these libraries to your SDK folder and specifying a parameter on the compilator command line executed.

You can try doing that with Flex 3 + Flash Player 11. If that doesn't work, then I'm afraid you can't debug anymore with Adobe Flash Debugger.

Luckily there are alternatives for debugging (unofficial products, but they can be great), you can for instance try using Intellij with Flex support to see if you can debug with this IDE. I have used Intellij for years with Flex and it is a great IDE, don't know if it will work with your project though.

Answer (score 1):

You can uninstall the current version of Flash through the Control Panel on Windows; then you can install 9.x.  See [this Adobe forum thread](http://forums.adobe.com/message/4487439) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

As Brian said you can uninstall the current version of Flash through the Control Panel on Windows; then you can install 9.x.

If it still doesn't work, check your project's compiler options-

In the Package explorer, right click on your project and open Properties. Now click on the Flex Compiler option. Set "Flex SDK version" to "Use a specific SDK (Flex 3)" and "Adobe Flash Player options" to "Use minimum version required by the Flex SDK".